# Sentence Detection with OpenNLP

Tags: java, nlp, nltk, tokenize, opennlp

I'm trying out OpenNLP sentence detection tool. The text is in a file - para3.txt. Contents:

```
Bob went to London Mary came from Paris Now everything is fine.
```

I'm running this with following command:

```
opennlp SentenceDetector ../models/en-sent.bin < para3.txt
```

I get the output like this:

```
Bob went to London Mary came from Paris Now everything is fine.
```

Ideally, I would have seen three sentences as output:

```
Bob went to London.
Mary came from Paris.
Now everything is fine.
```

Now, if I try for other sentences, where "full stop" or "period" is present, sentence detection is happening fine. A human would have guessed that there are 3 sentences in the text, but how to get it done by OpenNLP? What tools of NLP could help here??? What is the next level of sentence detection?

Comment: most trained models for sentence chunking are trying to discriminate between dots appearing as full stops or dots used for acronyms, titles, etc. You have a very specific case for which most likely you need to use a specialized technique or train a new model.

Answer (score 2):

you should train your model to detect these type of sentences i.e., sentence detector training as given in the documentation.
create your training file
 en-sent.train : Sample training data file. The only requirement is that each sentence should be on a separate line in the training file like below.

Sentence 1

Sentence 2

Sentence 3

……

……

then using command line interface:

```
opennlp SentenceDetectorTrainer -model en-sent_trained.bin -lang en -data en-sent.train -encoding UTF-8
```

this will give a model file :  en-sent_trained.bin

now use this .bin file instead of en-sent.bin

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a malformed text actually. You can use chucking information to divide it to sentences using some heuristics.